# jQuery css width not working in IE/Opera/FF but does in Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

So I'm working on a Wordpress theme at the moment but I'm having issues getting the blog to style properly.

I'm using some basic jQuery to get the width of the div with the content and then have that set the width of the wrapper called '.main'.

```
var blogWidth = $("#blogImages").width();
var blogTotal = blogWidth;
var totalCanvas = blogTotal;    
$('.main').css('width',totalCanvas);
```

It detects the proper width in Chrome but nothing else:
http://leighmcd.com/blog/blog

The other issue was that I need the images to sit to the right of the content, even though they are in the same post so I put a div around the images and absolute positioned it. I have a feeling this may also be affecting the structure.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use `.float{ float: right;}` for the floating thing, but that should really be a separate question.

Comment: Also, I would recommend relying on the natural flow of the document as much as possible.  Meaning, you should really just let .main calculate its own width.  At least keep that out of your javascript and in your stylesheets.  also, also,**Check out Ariel Fleslers** *scrolling plugins*:  http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jqueryscrollto.html - scrollTo, serialScroll, and localScroll will send you in the right direction for the effect you seem to be going for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [width](http://api.jquery.com/width/) to set the matched element's width:

```
$('.main').width(totalCanvas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding units to your `.css()` call:

```
$('.main').css('width',totalCanvas+'px');
```

Comment: Those seem to be ok, I'm now thinking it's a CSS issue. I have a wrapper around the whole blog entry but if I don't set a width to it the text will float. But when I set a width instead of auto the images will start wrapping. Even though I have white-space:nowrap;